# Is it possible to create an IObservable from an Action listener?

Tags: events, action, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a class that has an event defined as an `Action<Guid>`, as opposed to a classic EventHandler with EventArgs.  Is there a way to convert this to an IObservable the same way would be done with a standard EventHandler?  I need to do this so I can merge with other IObservables.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public event Action<Guid> Guid;
}
```

Then this is the code you need to turn the non-standard event into an `IObservable<Guid>`:

```
var foo = new Foo();

var guids = Observable.FromEvent<Guid>(
    h => foo.Guid += h,
    h => foo.Guid -= h);
```

Comment: I got back around to trying this, and it doesn't work.  I get an error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: @Random - I just tested my code above and it works fine. Are you using the "1.0" version of Rx?

Comment: No.  I'm using v2.0.50727 of System.Reactive.

Comment: @Random - There isn't a v2.0.50727 for System.Reactive. That version number is the .NET framework version number that it targets. Look for the assembly version number and let me know what that is.

Comment: @Random - No worries, but do feel free to accept my answer if you feel it would have been right. :-)